# Twilio error message "No routes found"

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I'm using Twilio's JavaScript SDK to make outgoing calls from the browser, I tried calling a number and didn't get any error messages directly from the console, but a voice came on and said "No routes found.". Could anybody verify what this means? It doesn't happen to every number, just a few. I tried finding information on what it means on Twilio's site and didn't have much luck. I'm not sure if this is even a question to be asked on SO, but I thought I'd give it a shot.

Comment: That's interesting, I've not experienced that before. Did anything come up in the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger)?

Comment: You might have geographical restriction in your twilio security.

Comment: @philnash Wow, I hadn't seen anything in the debugger, but it turns out I forgot to select the proper child account in Twilio. Turns out it's an error for an invalid phone number.

Comment: Ah, glad that sorted it!

Comment: FYI: I just experienced the same when calling a specific Norwegian mobile number via our Asterisk setup in Hawaii. After the "No routes found" voice (from Twilio I suspect), Asterisk's Allison tells me "All circuits are busy now, please try your call again later". Nothing shows in Twilio's debugger and the recipient confirmed the number is still in use.